# Codepen and JSFiddle have different results with same code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to learn some tab Javascript by studying Codepen examples, but every time I paste the code to another place, it all changes. To show you what I mean, I took the html, css, and JS from this pen and pasted it directly to a JSFiddle, which got me a broken result.

http://codepen.io/todd01925/pen/awGzD

http://jsfiddle.net/PJu8b/

...

`thanks for the help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in codepen you can use LESS and on jsfiddle you can't ;)
Only LESS allow to nested css.

Fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/PJu8b/2/

So instead of:

```
.tabs {
  li { ...}
  a { ...}
```

do:

```
.tabs li {...}
.tabs a {...}
```

Comment: hmm the code is still broken for me... am I missing something?

Another example, no LESS, but the tabs still don't work in jsfiddle:
http://codepen.io/CoffeeCupDrummer/pen/qmIdx ...and...
http://jsfiddle.net/5fv9B/